# Is a birth certificate enough for a Nexus child application?

Tags: nexus

With a Nexus application, is a birth certificate enough for identification or do they require a photo ID/passport?

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly implied that [a birth certificate is sufficient](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/application-demande-eng.html#child18):

> Children under 18
>   When both parents have legal custody, and only one parent or legal guardian 
>   is present, a letter of consent is required from the absent parent.
>
> If a parent has sole custody, or if only one parent is recorded on the minor's birth certificate, a consent letter is not required.
>
> If the parents or legal guardian have a custody agreement, it must be provided. The custody agreement must confirm that the child can legally leave Canada.
>
> If a child attends the interview with a person other than their parent or legal guardian, both parents or legal guardians must submit letter(s) of consent in addition to the other requirements.
>
> Minors can be enrolled in the NEXUS program even if their parents or legal guardians are not members.

Specific document requirements [can be found here](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/application-demande-eng.html); click on "Step 2 - Gather Documents" for full details:

> The following documents are accepted as proof of Canadian or U.S.
>   citizenship/admissibility and permanent residency:
>
> Canadian or U.S. citizen
>
> In Canada a valid passport; a birth
>   certificate and photo ID; a Canadian citizenship certificate or card;
>   or a Certificate of Indian Status.
>
> In the United States a valid
>   passport; a birth certificate and photo ID; a U.S. citizenship
>   certificate; a certificate of naturalization; or a border crossing
>   card.
>
> Canadian or U.S. permanent resident
>   In Canada a valid Permanent
>   Resident Card; or a Record of Landing. In the United States a valid
>   Permanent Resident Card Working or studying in Canada or the United
>   States a work permit; or a study permit.

Comment: How do you know the OP is Canadian?

Comment: @CGCampbell The reciprocal requirements from the US are parallel.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie The question is whether they're North American citizens or permanent resident non-North Americans.

Comment: @Coke That might be an academic question.  If they're foreign permanent residents, they would have arrived with passports, or been born in Canada or the US in which case they are citizens of the country in question.

Comment: https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/application-demande-eng.html The "Gather Documents" section outlines the precise requirements for US citizens, Canadian citizens, and eligible foreign citizens, which I'll also integrate into my answer.